# Timesteps with ignoring certain values

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I'm currently working on a lstm which use as data energy produced from solar panels collect every 5 minutes. We currently use a time step of 4 and we use "the 20 minutes" before to predict the values of the solar production of the 25 minutes.

We want to see if it's possible to predict not the 25 minutes but the 30 minutes and more and we currently predict on the training and test data to compare the results.

So what I understand is to make the model use a time step of t-2 to t-5 instead of a time step of t-1 to t-4.

I search for a way to accomplish this, but I don't know if it possible to make the time step skip some value?

Or it's possible to not change the time steps and make the model predict a value ahead like t+1?

I'm a beginner on RNN so I may misunderstand something, but feel free to tell me if it's the case